# Codeigniter foreach view table layout

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, codeigniter

Struggling to build an html table layout.  Here's what I want to display:

```
Player | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3
  1    |   11   |   19   |   7
  2    |   14   |   12   |   10
  3    |    9   |   15   |   13
```

But here is all I have been able to get:

```
Player | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3
  1    |   11   |        |   
  1    |   19   |        |   
  1    |    7   |        |   
  2    |   14   |        |   
  2    |   12   |        |   
  2    |   10   |        |   
  3    |    9   |        |   
  3    |   15   |        |   
  3    |   13   |        |
```

The values come from a single table (`results`) with columns 'Player', 'Week', and 'Score'

Here is the function in the model:

```
public function get_results(){
    for($plyr=1;$plyr<3;$plyr++) {
      $this->db->select('player, week, score');
      $this->db->from('results');
      $this->db->group_by(array('player','week'));

      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
    }   
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<?php foreach($results as $result) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $result->player; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result->score; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm clueless how to loop through this to display it as shown above. I tried nesting foreach loops in the view, but no luck.  Can't think of how a nested foreach might work in the model function, especially since I only want the Player # to iterate only once while each of their weekly scores follow along in the same row.

edit: i have made the tables clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pivot Results**

If you always have 3 weeks, you can pivot your results by using conditional aggregation to get the score for each week

```
  $this->db->select("player, 
    sum(case when week = 'Week 1' then score end) 'Week 1',
    sum(case when week = 'Week 2' then score end) 'Week 2',
    sum(case when week = 'Week 3' then score end) 'Week 3'");
  $this->db->from('results');
  $this->db->group_by('player');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
```

**Alternative: Reindex Data in PHP**

Another solution is to keep your current query and to reindex the data in php first by player then by week so that every `player,week` key is mapped to a `score`.

```
$resultsByPlayer = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    $resultsByPlayer[$result->player][$result->week] = $result->score;
}

foreach($resultsByPlayer as $player => $resultsByWeek) {
    print "<tr><td>$player</td>";
    ksort($resultsByWeek);
    foreach($resultsByWeek as $week => $score) {
        print "<td>$score</td>";
    }
    print "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I should have been more specific.  I will have more than 3 weeks - more than 20 in total.  I'm not averse to building 20 cases, but is there not a way to loop through this?

Comment: Tried the Alternative, getting: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array  Trying to work through it...

Comment: error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array is received on line:   $resultsByPlayer[$result['Player']][$result['week']] = $result['score'];   ...not sure how to work through that.  any thoughts?

Comment: FuzzyTree - thank you!  working now!  I can't upvote the answer - I don't have enought experience points apparently.  Once I do I will come back to upvote this.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: From your database design, you have to change the logic that you apply with this situation. Every single query to your database table or `Result` model should only grab all weeks and its respective scores for a single player ordered by week.